# How can i downgrade the gradle on project kotlin multiplatform to use a Android Studio Stable version?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Recently i started to work on a kotlin multiplatform project, i did not have any previous experience when i started, and i got the project with its base already created. The developer that create the project had the ideia to use the compose library on android development part.
Then he quit the job, and i started in it.
But i choose to not use compose because of the rush on deliver the application.

So the project gradle version is currently on `6.8` and android plugin on `7.0.0-alpha05`
but i want to downgrade to stop to use the Android Studio on Canary version, and use on a stable version. But when i downgrade the gradle i am getting this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':shared'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > /Users/jhonata/Documents/Projetos/Aurea/quicktendr-mgmt/shared/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':shared'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:191)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at ...
```

gradle properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

shared gradle:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}
android {
    configurations {
        create("androidTestApi")
        create("androidTestDebugApi")
        create("androidTestReleaseApi")
        create("testApi")
        create("testDebugApi")
        create("testReleaseApi")
    }
}

kotlin {
//    jvm()
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
                when (val target = this.compilation.target.name) {
                    "iosX64" -> {
                        export(Deps.Decompose.iosX64)
                    }

                    "iosArm64" -> {
                        export(Deps.Decompose.iosArm64)
                    }

                    else -> error("Unsupported target: $target")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(Deps.Decompose.decompose)
                api(Deps.coroutines)
                implementation(Deps.ktxSerializationJson)
                implementation(Deps.ktorCore)
                implementation(Deps.ktorSerialization)
                implementation(Deps.kissMeCommon)
                implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
                implementation("dev.icerock.moko:mvvm-core:0.10.1")
                implementation("dev.icerock.moko:mvvm-livedata:0.10.1")
                api("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.15.1")
                api("dev.icerock.moko:mvvm:0.9.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:1.4.2")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:1.4.2")
            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }

//        val mobileMain by creating {
//            dependsOn(commonMain)
//            dependencies {
//
//            }
//        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.ktorAndroid)
                implementation(Deps.kissMeAndroid)
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.ktorIOS)
                implementation(Deps.kissMeIOS)
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
//        val jvmMain by getting {
//            dependencies {
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:1.4.2")
//            }
//        }

        named("iosX64Main") {
            dependencies {
                api(Deps.Decompose.iosX64)
            }
        }

        named("iosArm64Main") {
            dependencies {
                api(Deps.Decompose.iosArm64)
            }
        }
    }
}

multiplatformResources {
    multiplatformResourcesPackage = "com.quicktendr.mgmt" // required
    iosBaseLocalizationRegion = "es" // optional, default "en"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework =
        kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin-native-dependencies")
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev")
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/icerockdev/plugins")
    }
    dependencies {
        val kotlinVersion = "1.4.31"
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        classpath("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0")
        classpath("dev.icerock.moko:resources-generator:0.15.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/arkivanov/maven")
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/icerockdev/moko")
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/netguru/maven/")
        maven("https://repo.repsy.io/mvn/chrynan/public")
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to downgrade gradle, you can downgrade gradle in the gradle properties file which you posted.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

You would need to set this to the latest version supported by Android Studio 4.2.1. There are also compatibility considerations with the Android gradle plugin. You can see a compatibility matrix for that here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-2-0

Please be aware that if your project was using things like compose which relied on particular versions of AGP/Gradle, you might need to rewrite those pieces. It is okay to use the canary versions of android studio or recent versions of intellij - unless you are hitting some issue. You can use compose and old view classes together using `AndroidView`

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose

Answer (score 0):

To downgrade Gradle, you need to set the version you want in the build.gradle file for the project:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    .....
}
```

And then you need to also downgrade the Gradle wrapper, by setting the version in the gradle.wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Please note, that the Gradle version and the Gradle wrapper versions don't normally match. Just set the Gradle wrapper to the same version as your Gradle, and then Android Studio will correct it to the right version.

Comment: Has this changed recently? When I try to add classpath '...' to my dependencies it throws "Unresolved reference: classpath".

Comment: @LabGecko The "......" line in the dependencies is just a representation of other dependencies you might have. It is not to be used literary. You should not include that line with the dots in it.

Comment: I didn't mean it literally either. I meant that the listed classpath ( '''classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2''' ) throws an unresolved reference. Formatting was correct.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me on Android Studio Hedgehog (2023.1.1 Patch 1). The Hedgehog release added a `.toml` file for many configurations, but hasn't yet seemed to sync that file with the Project Structure settings.

The fix that worked for me:

1. In Android view under Gradle Scripts open
   `gradle-wrapper.properties`. Set the distribution to 8.2. This can
   also be done from the menu using File >> Project Structure >>
   Project >> Gradle Version >> set to `8.2`

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
   ```
2. Also under Gradle Scripts open `libs.versions.toml`. Set agp to `8.2.1`.
   Setting it to `8.2` resulted in an error.

   ```
   [versions]
   agp = "8.2.1"
   ```
3. I also had to **REMOVE** the Java compile options section from the app level `build.gradle` file. This may not apply to you. Also note that I am using Java 17. Yours is likely to be different. For example, Java 1.8 will show as `VERSION_1_8`. I changed this:

   ```
   android {
       kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "17" }
       compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility = VERSION_17
           targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
       }
       ... other settings ...
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   android {
       kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "17" }
       ... other settings ...
   }
   ```